# How to pass detected faces from a function to a separate push button slot in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing

I am using Qt for creating front-end,I have a method called 'facedetect',in that i detect all the faces.Now i need to pass those detected faces to another function,in that it compares detected faces with all the faces in the database.But the actual problem is ,I am comparing faces when i click a pushbutton 'compare'(It is in different slot). I need to access the detected faces in to the 'compare' pushbutton slots.
**Here is my code:**

```
void third::facedetect(IplImage* image) //face detection
{
int j=0,l=0,strsize,count=0;
char numstr[50];
CvPoint ul,lr,w,h;
string path;
IplImage* image1;IplImage* tmpsize;IplImage* reimg;
CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade=(CvHaarClassifierCascade*) cvLoad(cascade_name);                                                      
CvMemStorage* storage=cvCreateMemStorage(0);

if(!cascade)
{
    qDebug()<<"Coulid not load classifier cascade";

}
if(cascade)
{
    CvSeq* faces=cvHaarDetectObjects(image,cascade,storage,1.1,1,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,cvSize(10,10));

    for(int i=0;i<(faces ? faces->total : 0);i++)
    {
        string s1="im",re,rename,ex=".jpeg";
        sprintf(numstr, "%d", k);
        re = s1 + numstr;
        rename=re+ex;
        char *extract1=new char[rename.size()+1];
        extract1[rename.size()]=0;
        memcpy(extract1,rename.c_str(),rename.size());
        strsize=rename.size();
        CvRect *r=(CvRect*) cvGetSeqElem(faces,i);
        ul.x=r->x;
        ul.y=r->y;
        w.x=r->width;
        h.y=r->height;
        lr.x=(r->x + r->width);
        lr.y=(r->y + r->height);
        cvSetImageROI(image,cvRect(ul.x,ul.y,w.x,h.y));
        image1=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image),image->depth,image->nChannels);
        cvCopy(image, image1, NULL);
        reimg=resizeImage(image1, 40, 40, true);
        saveImage(reimg,extract1);
        img_1=cvarrToMat(reimg);//this img_1 contains the detected faces.
        cvResetImageROI(image);
        cvRectangle(image,ul,lr,CV_RGB(1,255,0),3,8,0);
        j++,count++,k++;

    }

}

qDebug()<<"Number of images:"<<count<<endl;
cvNamedWindow("output");//creating a window.
cvShowImage("output",image);//showing resized image.
cvWaitKey(0);//wait for user response.
cvReleaseImage(&image);//releasing the memory.
cvDestroyWindow("output");//destroying the window.
}

**And this the push button 'compare' slot**
void third::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{

}


If I could access those detected faces from  'void third::on_pushButton_5_clicked()'    then only I can use it in the push button slot'compare'. Please help me to fix this..
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a declaration problem... that the image showing the detected face is not declared under the "public", or maybe "global" variable. If so, its simple.

In your header file, `third.h`,

```
class third : public third
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit third(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~third();
//declare your image holding the detected face here, which see from your .cpp file is img_1
```

Following which, for your  `void third::on_pushButton_5_clicked()`,

```
void third::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
         cvNamedWindow("img_1");//creating a window.
         cvShowImage("img_1",img_1);//showing resized image.
         cvWaitKey(0);//wait for user response.
         cvReleaseImage(&img_1);//releasing the memory.
         cvDestroyWindow("img_1");//destroying the window.
}
```

The code may have complilation error, as I am typing this directly into stackOverflow.

Do let me know if that solves the problem, if so, do considering clicking the tick button under the arrows and upvoting it. If it doesn't work, comment, and I will see how else I can help. Cheers!

Comment: When I tried this method I could access only last detected faces.I need to access all the detected faces in push button slot.Then only I can compare all that face with faces which are in the database.

Comment: Meaning which, for example if I click detect face 5 times, all face images tat are detected during each 5 times will be saved? until you click on pushButton_5?

Comment: If you are clicking facedetect, then pushButton_5, then facedetect, then pushButton_5, then the case you are mentioning, shouldn't happen.

Comment: let me know which scenario you are after or if either scenario is not mentioned(:

Comment: No,when I click detect face button only once,it detect all the faces.(by pressing the right arrow I can see all the detected faces)Also I have another button compare,when I click that I need to compare all the faces.For that I need to access all the detected faces.

Comment: So the problem now is that when you click the detect face button, not all detected faces are shown? Have you tried display all the detected faces in the detect face button program? Or detect Face is able to show all detected faces but when you click on pushButton_5 that not all faces are shown?

Comment: This is because, you seen to be redrawing the image each time a face is detected in the for loop rather than adding in new faces, hence I think the problem is in your detect face button rather than my method of the pushButton_5.

Comment: Actually the problem is detect button shows all the images.For comparison purpose I need to access those detected faces in the compare push button slot.As you suggested earlier I tried that method(made img_1 as public),but I could access only the last detected face.Please help me as early as possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50118/discussion-between-rockinfresh-and-user3228547)

Comment: The thing is that I am not able to pass all the detected images to compare button slot
Please give me a reply..

Comment: Have you tried my last suggestion, of putting copying image to img_1? The Mat image method of that is `image.copyTo(img_1);` I am rather busy these days, else I would have you find the IplImage equivalent. If that doesn't work, then I am not really sure what to do. Since image holds all the detected faces, making an exact same copy of it named img_1 to be used in your compare button should work

Comment: Sorry this is not working.This method copy's only the last detected face from image to img_1.